# Special String splitting in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I would like to split a special formatted `string`:

```
string example01 = "2016-05-14-Title-863-Pos-01"
```

That `string` must be split into:

```
date = "2016-05-14";
title = "Title-863";
position = "Pos-01";
```

I know I can split this `string` with `string.split` or `Regex` but I would like to have a "split" function with formatted seperators or something similar.

More examples:

```
string example02 = "2016-05-15-Rectangle-Right"
string example03 = "2016-05-16-Border-05-Top"
```

Example-Method:

```
string[] split = SplitString("****-**-**", "-");
```

So the first parameter serves as a placeholder and the second parameter as seperator.

Comment: Seems like you could just split on "-" then join the first 3, the next 2 and the last two to get the desired results.  What do you mean by _I would like to have a "split" function with formatted seperators or something_?  Do you want to write your own function?

Comment: This would depend on many things. You could indeed use REGEX, which I still don't know how to use properly. But if your data will always follow this specific format, you could make it using split.

Comment: Is the string always in this exact format?

Comment: For goodness sake... If your data is always in this same format, spend two minutes and write a function that will parse it out for you using SubString, and then just call that function.

Comment: The format is not always exact. Title or position can also contain only text or only a number...

Comment: Can you please add some other examples of the string to your question? It would help people give a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generic BlockSplit method like this one

```
string[] BlockSplit(string source, char separator, params int[] blocks)
{
    string[] parts = source.Split(separator);
    List<string> splitted = new List<string>();

    int skipped = 0;
    foreach (int x in blocks)
    {
        string block = string.Join(separator.ToString(), parts.Skip(skipped).Take(x));
        skipped += x;
        splitted.Add(block);
    }
    return splitted.ToArray();
}
```

Calling this method with your inputs

```
string test = "2016-05-14-Title-863-Pos-01";
string[] result = BlockSplit(test, '-', new int[] {3,2,2});
foreach(string s in result)
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This could transformed in an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for the string class and and allow a syntax like this one

```
string test = "2016-05-14-Title-863-Pos-01";
string[] result = test.BlockSplit('-', new int[] {3,2,2});
```

Comment: This is not bad at all. Unfortunately, the format is not always the same. Date remains but the rest can be different.But I will remember this method. :)

Comment: Well, the only requirement here is that you have always the same separator between blocks, Of course you should supply the count for every block you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if the string is always in that exact format. If anything changes this becomes flakey:

```
// Original string, has to be in the exact format shown
var test = "2016-05-14-Title-863-Pos-01";

// Split into groups based on the '-' character
var split = test.Split('-');

// Uses string interpolation '$' to build new strings
var date = $"{split[0]}-{split[1]}-{split[2]}";
var title = $"{split[3]}-{split[4]}";
var position $"{split[5]}-{split[6]}";
```

Output:

> Date: 2016-05-14
>   Title: Title-863
>   Position: Pos-01

As pointed out by Phiter, if using an older version if C# then use:

```
var date = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", split[0], split[1], split[2]);
var title = split[3] + "-" + split[4];
var position = split[5] + "-" + split[6];
```

Comment: Gotta mention that this is available only in C# 6 or above. Previous versions won't accept string interpolation. E.g.: I tried to run your code on IDEONE and it threw an error on this symbol. They probably use an older version of C#.

Comment: Good point, added regular old `string.Format` and concatenation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the format is not always the same. Date remains however the rest ....

Comment: Put some other examples in your question, otherwise people are forced to guess...

Answer (score 0):

If your data format will always be the same, you can do it like this:

```
string test = "2016-05-14-Title-863-Pos-01";
string[] ts = test.Split('-');
string date = ts[0] + "-" + ts[1] + "-" + ts[2];
string title = ts[3] + "-" + ts[4];
string position = ts[5] + "-" + ts[6];

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Date: {0}\nTitle: {1}\nPosition: {2}", date,title,position));
```

**Output:**

> Date: 2016-05-14
>   Title: Title-863
>   Position: Pos-01

[See it in action.](http://ideone.com/WvjS28)

Comment: Unfortunately, the format is not always the same. Date remains however the rest ....

Comment: You should have specified in the question.